# Wrong order of list ul firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a strange trouble with firebase.

I have a list of users. Through the uid of each user I go to get information (name and logo) from another node. 
Sometimes, the list is not correctly created, the name and logo shown do not correspond to the ID that the item has. So I click on the first user but in reality it is not the right one

This doesn't always happen and I can't figure out how to fix it. Some idea?

```
function user_list() {

    var refClientiUlChat = firebase.database().ref('Chat').child('user');
    refClientiUlChat.on('value', chatDataUl);


    function chatDataUl(data) {

        document.getElementById("spinner-id").style.display='none';

        //necessario per svuotare la lista se no quando si aggiorna la ricrea da capo
        $("#chat-user-ul").empty();

        //ottenere la key
        var clientiUser = data.val();
        var keys = Object.keys(clientiUser);
        //console.log(keys [0]);






        //ricevere i dati e creare gli elementi
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
            var k = keys[i];
            var clientUid = clientiUser[k].uid;


            (function(z) {
                var m = keys[z];
                var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('Clienti/' + clientiUser[m].uid);
                starCountRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {

                    var clientiUser2 = snapshot.val();

                    var name = clientiUser2.name;
                    var logo = clientiUser2.logo;

                    if (clientiUser[m].uid !== clientiUser2.uid){
                        name = clientiUser[m].uid + ' -- ' + clientiUser2.uid;
                    }


                    if (logo == null){
                        logo = 'https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fcdn1.iconfinder.com%2Fdata%2Ficons%2Fflat-business-icons%2F128%2Fuser-512.png&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.iconfinder.com%2Ficons%2F1287507%2Faccount_avatar_human_people_profile_user_icon&docid=t2K2xM0hzlED1M&tbnid=u4nqtyxkwLW87M%3A&vet=10ahUKEwjE7Lmu-6_lAhUpPewKHenMAQcQMwhHKAIwAg..i&w=512&h=512&bih=682&biw=1536&q=account%20image%20flat&ved=0ahUKEwjE7Lmu-6_lAhUpPewKHenMAQcQMwhHKAIwAg&iact=mrc&uact=8'
                    }


                    var badge = clientiUser[m].badgeFood;

                    var  visibilityBadge = 'hidden';

                    if (badge === undefined || badge=== null || badge=== 'false'){
                        visibilityBadge = 'hidden';

                    }else {
                        visibilityBadge = 'visible';

                    }


                    //var layout = "<li ><div ><h4><b>" + name + "</b></h4></div></li>";
                    var layout = "<li><div id='chat-user-item'><div id='chat-user-img-div'><img src='"+logo+"' alt='logo' ></div><div id='chat-user-name-div'><b>" + name + "</b></div><div id='chat-user-badge-div'><div style='visibility:"+visibilityBadge+"'></div></div></div></li>";

                    $("#chat-user-ul").append(layout);


                });

            })(i);

        }

        var ulList = document.getElementById('chat-user-ul');
        ulList.addEventListener('click', function(e){

            //refClientiUlChat.off('value', chatDataUl);

            var li = e.target.closest('li');
            var nodes = Array.from( li.closest('ul').children );
            var index = nodes.indexOf( li );

            if( e.target.nodeName === "DIV"||e.target.nodeName === "P" || e.target.nodeName === "IMG" || e.target.nodeName === "B") {

                closeList_user();

                clienteuid = clientiUser[keys [index]].uid;

                chatUl(clienteuid);

                sessionStorage.setItem('chat-uid', clienteuid);
            }
        });

    }

}
```